# RS485 waveform distortion

Tags: rs485, signal-integrity

I was checking RS485 signals with an oscilloscope and saw some waveforms which look distorted (see right side of image PIC1).

See schematic for test points TP1, TP2.

**Setup**

- Probe 1:- TP2 and GND
- Probe 2:- TP1 to GND
- Oscilloscope Earth terminal was disconnected.

**Channel Setting**

- Ch1 :- RS485+ (TP2)  Red Color
- Ch2 :- RS485- (TP1) Yellow color
- Math Ch2-Ch1 =  Green Color

**Oscilloscope trace images**

- PIC1 : is the waveform when RS485 communication active and other device is connected.
- PIC2 :- expanded view (zoom) of right side part of waveform PIC1
- PIC3 :- expanded view (zoom) of left side part of waveform PIC1

**Questions**

- Why is the amplitude changed on half of the waveform?
- Has anyone seen this before?
- Why does this only happen when the other RS485 device is connected at the opposite end?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is a xoom?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič - it's even cooler than a zoom.

Comment: It looks like your 'opposite end other device' is trying to drive the bus at the same time.

Comment: Its Zoom, by mistake wrote xoom.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the amplitude changed on half of the waveform?
>
> Why does this only happen when the other RS485 device is connected at the opposite end?

The simple answer is that the "other" RS485 device must be *heavily* loading the bus - probably by trying to drive it at the same time as the "first" RS485 device (as *brhans* also suggested in a comment).

Remember that RS485 defines an *electrical interface*, but not a *protocol*. As shown in the schematic, you are using normal half-duplex RS485 on a 2-wire bus. Therefore it is up to the system designer to implement a communications protocol which prevents more than one RS485 device (node) transmitting at the same time.

Assuming that both devices use the same schematic, then you need to ensure that only *one* RS485 device uses signal `UART4_TXEN` to drive the bus, at any given time.

If one device can be considered a "Master" and the other considered a "Slave", then having the Master device *poll* the Slave device, using appropriate switching between Tx and Rx modes on each device so that they are not both in Tx mode at the same time, can be considered as the start of a protocol definition.

However if, in your system, both devices could transmit at *any* time (including at the *same* time) then you could consider using a full-duplex bus between them e.g. what is sometimes called 4-wire RS485 (which is really just two, 2-wire RS485 buses). That is only a potential solution in a simple two-device point-to-point configuration.

The topic of which RS485 protocol to use has been discussed in previous questions. Modbus is one standard.

Comment: Yes Opposite end use the Same Schematics, and we used mod bus protocol.

Comment: @Transformer - Thanks. (a) That is important new info. Please edit the question & add *all* the system info you have including *exact* details of system design, cabling, RS-485 common wire usage etc. (b) Please add some history to the question e.g. Is the h/w new? Is the s/w new? Which parts have been tested successfully elsewhere? (c) Now you've said Modbus is being used, move the two devices close to each other and use a 'scope to view both `UART4_TXEN` signals (one on Ch1, the other on Ch2) when the reduced RS-485 signal amplitudes occur. Please add that trace at the end of the question.